# If the norm of a sequence of functions is bounded in $L^{p+\beta}$, then $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that a sequence of functions $f_n$ converges to $f$ on a set of finite measure. Also, for some positive $\beta$, there exists some $M$ such that
$$
\lvert| f_n \rvert|_{p+\beta} \leq M.
$$
Then, $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p(E)$.

I thought that this could be proved using DCT, which didn't work. Can anyone give a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean that the space $E$ has finite measure and that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for almost every $x$.

You can write, for $K > 0$ :

$$ \Vert f_n - f \Vert_{L^p} \leq \Vert (f_n - f) \mathbb{1}_{|f_n - f| \leq K} \Vert_{L^p} + \Vert (f_n - f) \mathbb{1}_{|f_n - f| > K} \Vert_{L^p} $$

The first one goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ ($K$ is fixed) by the DCT.

On the other hand, you know that $\mathbb{1}_{|f_n - f| > K}$ also goes to $0$ in $L^q$ by the DCT, for every $q \geq 1$. By interpolation (Hölder's inequality), you have that :

$$ \Vert (f_n - f) \mathbb{1}_{|f_n - f| > K} \Vert_{L^p} \leq \Vert \mathbb{1}_{|f_n - f| > K} \Vert_{L^q} \Vert f_n - f \Vert_{L^{p+\beta}} $$

for some $\alpha > 0$ and some $q$ (independant of $n$). This also goes to $0$ and you are done.

Comment: To use the Hölder inequality, I think it's $|| f \cdot g||_1 \leq ||f||_p \cdot ||g||_q$? Also, just to clarify, $q$ is the conjugate of $p+\beta$, right? I just edited the questions as I noticed that it should be $||f_n||_{p+\beta} \leq M$.

Comment: The Hölder's inequality can be generalized to $\Vert f g \Vert_{L^p} \leq \Vert f \Vert_{L^q} \Vert g \Vert_{L^r}$ whenever $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}$. If you already know Hölder, this should be easy to prove.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about the generalized Hölder's inequality. For the second part, $||\chi_{|f_n - f| > K}||$ goes to $0$, is it due to the continuity of integration and thus the measure of the set we are integrating over goes to zero?

Comment: Well, you can see it like that or simplier through the DCT : for almost every $x$, it goes to $0$ and is dominated by $1$.

Comment: I am also curious whether we really used the fact that $||f_n||_{p+\beta} \leq M$ for some $M$ here?

Comment: At the very last step, you have $\Vert \mathbb{1}_{|f_n - f| > K} \Vert \to 0$ and need $\Vert f_n - f \Vert$ to remain bounded when $n$ varies (it helps here).

Comment: I don't think there should be any exponents $\alpha$ or $1-\alpha$. Where do these come from?

Comment: Indeed, I confused it with something else !

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^{1 + \beta}/x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, $\{|f_n|^p : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly integrable. By the uniform integrability $L^p$ convergence theorem, it follows that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$.